# After checking a checkbox or more and submitting, a portion of the checkbox disappears

Tags: html, css, web-development-server

I don't have any javascript, just html5 and css3. I use python to process the user data and the python processes the data correctly.
However, the disappearing portion comes back after I reload the page (not refreshing it). Why is it doing this?
(It's a self-processing page that shows the checkboxes after processing the data,  the checkbox labels change slightly after user puts in data )

```
connection=db.connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname')
cursor=connection.cursor(db.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT name, club, playingPosition FROM PLAYERSWD2 ORDER BY playingPosition")
if cursor.rowcount == 0:
    checkboxPlayers="<p>Sorry. There are no players at present.</p>"
else:
    cursor.execute("SELECT name, club, playingPosition, value, playerteam FROM PLAYERSWD2 WHERE playingPosition='goalkeeper' ORDER BY name")
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        slicing=row["name"][:3]
        goalkeeper+="<label for='%s'>%s, Team: %s, Position: %s, Value: %s, User: %s</label><input type='checkbox' name='goalkeeper' value='%s' id='%s' />" % (slicing, row["name"], row["club"], row["playingPosition"], row["value"], row["playerteam"], row["name"], slicing)

    cursor.execute("SELECT name, club, playingPosition, value, playerteam FROM PLAYERSWD2 WHERE playingPosition='defender' ORDER BY name")
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        if row["name"]=="David Luiz" or row["name"]=="Antonio Rudiger" or row["name"]=="Marcos Alonso"  or row["name"]=="Nicolas Otamendi":
            slicing1=row["name"][:3]+"1"
        else:
            slicing1=row["name"][:3]
        defender+="<label for='%s'>%s, Team: %s, Position: %s, value: %s, User: %s</label><input type='checkbox' name='defender' value='%s' id='%s' />" % (slicing1, row["name"], row["club"], row["playingPosition"], row["value"], row["playerteam"], row["name"], slicing1)

    cursor.execute("SELECT name, club, playingPosition, value, playerteam FROM PLAYERSWD2 WHERE playingPosition='midfielder' ORDER BY name")
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        if row["name"]=="Dani Ceballos" or row["name"]=="Bernardo Silva" or row["name"]=="Mason Mount":
            slicing2=row["name"][:3]+"1"
        elif row["name"]=="David Silva":
            slicing2=row["name"][:3]+"2"
        else:
            slicing2=row["name"][:3]
        midfielder+="<label for='%s'>%s, Team: %s, Position: %s, value: %s, User: %s</label><input type='checkbox' name='midfielder' value='%s' id='%s' />" % (slicing2, row["name"], row["club"], row["playingPosition"], row["value"], row["playerteam"], row["name"], slicing2)

    cursor.execute("SELECT name, club, playingPosition, value, playerteam FROM PLAYERSWD2 WHERE playingPosition='forward' ORDER BY name")
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        if row["name"]=="Sergio Aguero" or row["name"]=="Willian":
            slicing3=row["name"][:3]+"1"
        else:
            slicing3=row["name"][:3]
        forward+="<label for='%s'>%s, Team: %s, Position: %s, value: %s, User: %s</label><input type='checkbox' name='forward' value='%s' id='%s' />" % (slicing3, row["name"], row["club"], row["playingPosition"], row["value"], row["playerteam"], row["name"], slicing3)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. We need to see a [mcve] of your code. Additionally, why would you expect a checkbox not to appear after you load the page freshly?

Comment: this is vague and its better to post what you have now, otherwise how can we help ?

Comment: edited, it's a self-processing page, the checkbox labels change slightly after user puts in data